# Angular - getting the handle to the ng-content component in the parent

Tags: angular

I have a higher level, general purpose component, the child component will implement an interface.

I need to get a handle to the child component into the higher level, parent component.  In the following snippet I've tried to get the #contentComponent referenced into the parent component (your looking at the html of the parent component) using a @viewChild to null avail.

I've also tried using an elementRef on the div around it the ng-content and looking through the children. I find the ng-content's component div but I don't know how to turn this into reference of the component.

```js
<div style="width: 100%">
  <paper-card [heading]="documentIndex.name" class="mix-browser-container">
    <div>
      <ng-content #contentComponent></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div>
      <paginator #paginator [documentIndex]="documentIndex"></paginator>
    </div>
  </paper-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> @viewChild

In order to access the `<ng-content>` tag, you'll need to use ContentChild.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ContentChild-decorator.html

Comment: doesn't this assume that the type of the ng-content control is known? In my context, I don't know the type; although, i could try an interface on the child control.

Comment: ContentChild and ViewChild should be able to take selectors like css -- you could try giving the ng-content an ID or Class and selecting it that way?